# Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: python, django

I tried to sum the data from my database using below code.

models.py

```
class Income(models.Model):
    Total= models.CharField(max_length=512,null =True,blank=True)
```

views.py :

```
Total_income = Income.objects.filter(Q(title='Salary')| Q(title='Bonus')).aggregate(Sum('Total'))
```

But I got this error when I try to run it.

**('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator. (8117) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')**

I'm new to Python and Django so I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Which database and engine are you using? Can you share your DATABASES setting

Comment: Actually I have figured out this error. I just changed my code in views.py to Total_income = Income.objects.filter(Q(title='Salary')| Q(title='Bonus')).annotate(as_float=Cast('Total', FloatField())).aggregate(Sum('as_float')) and it's work. But thanks anyway for reaching out to me hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `SUM` `CharField` not `Integer`, that's why you see the error. So you need to make that field integer, or if for any reason you need it to left as `CharField`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Income.objects.filter(
    Q(title='Salary')| Q(title='Bonus')
).annotate(
    total_as_float=Cast('Total', FloatField()
).aggregate(Sum('total_as_float'))
```